# Is it possible to use the comfortaa font without setting it as the default?

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to use the comfortaa font for just a selected section of a document in XeLaTeX?  I am quite inexperienced and am not sure how fonts work, and can currently only get it to work for either all of the document or none of it.

Comment: The truetype font files are part of the package, so you can use the font with `fontspec` under xelatex or lualatex: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\fmyc{Comfortaa}
\begin{document}
Default text 123456789. {\fmyc Comfortaa font text 123456789.}
\end{document}`

Comment: The above code finds the ttf files in the texmf tree: `texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/aajohan/comfortaa/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf`

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the settings from the style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\comfortaa{Comfortaa}[
    Extension=.ttf,%
    Ligatures={TeX,Common},%
    FontFace={l}{n}{*-Light},%
    FontFace={l}{it}{Font=*-Light,FakeSlant=0.167},%
    UprightFont={*-Regular},%
    ItalicFont={*-Regular},%
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.167},%
    FontFace={b}{n}{*-Bold},%
    FontFace={b}{it}{Font=*-Bold,FakeSlant=0.167},%
    BoldFont={*-Bold},%
    BoldItalicFont={*-Bold},%
    BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.167}]
 
\begin{document}

Some normal text, \textit{italic} and \textbf{bold}.

{\comfortaa Some text in Comfortaa, \textit{italic} and \textbf{bold}.}

Some normal text, \textit{italic} and \textbf{bold}.
\end{document}
```

[image]